# How to convert a string into a integer type

Tags: c, string, int

Starting with a string such as “234.89”, convert it

to a number without using built-in  string  to

number  conversion  methods.

Comment: Try splitting every bit and convert each to an int, than the number on the left to INT and add the right ones: 234(int)+0.89

Comment: At least paste it properly...

Comment: And how exactly 234.89 can be converted to "integer type"?

Comment: @EugeneSh. how _dare_ you miss the _homework_ tag? ;-)

Comment: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/libkern/strtol.c

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, if an int cannot store a decimal value. You might want to do some more reading on C data types. There are methods already built to do it for you, but you since this seems like a HW assignment, you want to implement it yourself.

I recommend you loop through each character in the string, and convert that to an int. You will have to deal with some base 10 stuff to get the places right.